# why does rbind need a loop to create a data frame and not just a vector of matrixes

Tags: r

```
for (i in 1:5) {
        dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_full[i]))
```

works, but

```
dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_full[1:5]))
```

doesn't:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument

`files_full` returns this:

```
[1] "diet_data/Andy.csv"  "diet_data/David.csv" "diet_data/John.csv" 
[4] "diet_data/Mike.csv"  "diet_data/Steve.csv"
```

from this exercise:
https://github.com/rdpeng/practice_assignment/blob/master/practice_assignment.rmd

Comment: It's not about `rbind`, but about `read.csv`, which won't take a vector of file names as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

`rbind()` is meant to bind all it's parameters, not elements contained in lists inside of its parameters. For example

```
dat <- rbind(read.csv(files_full[1]), read.csv(files_full[2], read.csv(files_full[3])
```

would work. If you want to turn a list into parameter, you use `do.call`

```
dat <- do.call("rbind", Vectorize(read.csv, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)(files_full))
```

Here I used `Vectorize()` to allow `read.csv` to return a list when given a vector of file names.

Comment: I upvoted but I don't really think the first sentence is a good description of what `rbind.data.frame` actually does. It does in fact "bind" the elements inside the lists which are its arguments.